# how to link a satisfaction app with results dashboard?

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio, survey, mbaas

I developed an Android application for my company to measure the satisfaction of our clients in our stores. I developed the front end with all the screens and the design in Android studio, and I generate the APK for the approval of the directors board. Now I want to develop a dashboard to see results of the application.

Each store has one tablet and the app is already installed. I want to link the answers (Happy - Moderate - Not happy) to a dashboard to show the daily/monthly results.

Honestly I know a little in coding but I'm fast learner if you can show me tutos or books to read quickly .. I heard about something like Back end as service.. is it the right way to begin searching ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want connect your app with the dashboard database. So i am gonna share to you 2 approach.

**Approach 1**

You can share a database between dashboard and app. If you see the picture you can see that the dashboard presents the data in the screen and the android app Send the anwswer to the database.

[image]

**Approach 2**
If you already has the dashboard with a database, you also can create a table for daily/monthly results and create a service to push the data from the Android app.

[image]

For the approach number 1 you can take a look to Firebase Database, and then connect the Dashboard and App to the database.

For the approach number 2 you need to take a look how to create a web service and then update the database with the data received.

I hope it helps you.